# MySQL: Count total "value" for each occurrence

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there some query "magic" that can do what I'm looking for or it must be done with programmatically with the returned result?

I have the table "bones":

```
    Color   Amount   Length
    -----------------------
    yellow  3        15
    brown   2        16
    white   4        10
    yellow  2        11
    black   2        15
    white   1        15
    brown   2        16
    white   4        10
    yellow  1        11
    black   2        15
```

I actually want to get a view on this that I see it is sorted by total amount of bones of each color and see the amount as well.
Which should look like:

```
    Color   Amount   
    -----------------------
    white   9
    yellow  6
    brown   4
    black   4
```

But so far I've figured out only following query:

```
SELECT Color,COUNT(*) as count FROM tablename GROUP BY Color ORDER BY count DESC;
```

But that gives me:

```
    Color   Amount   
    -----------------------
    white   3
    yellow  3
    brown   2
    black   2
```

Which is a count of occurrences with distinct values, but not what I really looking for.
Is it possible within one query? And if such magic possible how do I extend it? e.g. I count the same but let's say for bones that longer then 11cm?

Comment: Use `sum(amount)` instead of `count(*)`

Comment: sum(amount) as amount

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT Color,SUM(amount) as count FROM tablename
GROUP BY Color ORDER BY count DESC;
```

**COUNT**= Count No. Of Occurrences,

**SUM**= Gives Addition Columns Data

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
SUM(amount)
```

instead of

```
COUNT(*)
```

since SUM() adds all the values in that grouping, whereas COUNT() only counts the number of occurrences that is NOT  NULL